# How can I convert my web app to Angular 4 without Node.js/NPM

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, angular

I currently am using java/html/css/js for my web app. I want to add Angular 4 into my webapp without using Node.js or NPM. Instead I would like to use Java.

Does anyone have any recommendations, examples, or ways I could go about doing this?

I imported the angular.min.js file into my project directory and added in some demo Angular code but it's not working. After running ng-build, I receive an error saying: "node_modules appears empty, you may need to run `npm install`"

Comment: You will need typescript compiler at the very least in order to compile the angular project...

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use node during development? If you don't want to then probably better you don't use angular 4 and use angular 1.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import the angular js file by downloading it into your project or referencing an angular CDN.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Assuming you are using java servlets, create a new JSP with a controller endpoint mapped to it. Import the angular script on that JSP and you'll be good to go.